# How to revise the token from GitHub stored in ServiceNow (ServiceNow Studio "Edit Repository Configuration")

Tags: github, token, credentials, servicenow

After much futile searching ...

The mis-named ServiceNow Studio "Edit Repository Configuration" does not allow you to update an expired GitHub token.

In ServiceNow, navigate to "Connections & Credentials".  In the UTAH version, I have four choices. One choice is "Credentials".  The table that appears has a list of the credentials I see in the ServiceNow Studio "Edit Repository Configuration".  Studio does not let you change a token, only use a token in the "Credentials" table.  When you edit a row in the Credentials table, the user name and  password textboxes are presented.  The "password" is actually the token string from GitHub.

Instructions for making a new developer token in GitHub is well explained in a few posts.  Settings --> Developer Settings --> Personal Access Tokens.  There are two choices here. "Fine Grained" and "Classic".  I stayed with Classic for fear ServiceNow isn't ready for anything overly complex security-wise.  I picked the "repo" check box in the OAuth scopes offerings.

Comment: What is your question? This looks more like a blog post or gist? You can answer your own question, but there needs to be at least a question.

Comment: In ServiceNow, how do you to update an expired GitHub token?